# What does "has additional properties" mean in an error message about an .eslintrc file?

Tags: eslint

I am making an .eslintrc file that includes an "indent" rule. The configuration for the rule is as follows:

```
  "indent": ["error", 2, {
    ...,
    "FunctionDeclaration": {"parameters": 2, "body": 1},
    "FunctionExpression": {"parameters": 2, "body": 1},
  }]
```

However, when running eslint I receive the error:

```
Configuration for rule "indent" is invalid:
Value "data["1"].FunctionDeclaration" has additional properties.
Value "data["1"].FunctionExpression" has additional properties.
```

What does this error message mean? I would guess that it means that either (a) there are more properties that are mandatory for the FunctionDeclaration, which aren't there, or (b) one of the properties ("parameters" or "body") that are in the function declaration aren't supposed to be there. I think that I can rule out (b) because when I change the .eslintrc file to:

```
  "indent": ["error", 2, {
    ...,
    "FunctionDeclaration": {},
    "FunctionExpression": {},
  }]
```

I receive the same error message, even though there are no properties. And all the documentation that I have been able to find says that the only properties needed are "parameters" and "body", I haven't been able to find anything that indicates there are properties needed other than this. What is the problem here?

Comment: You've specified neither `parameters` nor `body` for `FunctionDeclaration` or `FunctionExpression`, so their inclusion in your `.eslintrc` is somewhat pointless. I image that's the gist of the error.

Comment: As I mentioned, I still get the error even when I do include the "parameters" and "body" properties.

Comment: Indeed. I misread the question. What version of eslint are you using? I don't see the error with either of your rule configurations.

Comment: By any chance is your `eslint --version` less than v3.5.0?

Comment: I'm on 3.5.0, and have this same issue with a proper definition: `"indent"       : [2, 2, { "SwitchCase": 1, "FunctionDeclaration": {"body": 1, "parameters": 2}}],`

Comment: @AlexanderMont this post is already a few years old, I suppose you found a fix?

Otherwise, you can try running `eslint` with the `--debug` flag and also look into https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8437 which describes a similar issue.

Comment: In case, anyone needs, there are similar issues on the ESLint repo: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22has+additional+properties%22